# Bash: Create copy of music files in different format and folder

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, copy, find

I'm trying to create a bash scipt to simply automate finding my flac files and creating an alac copy of them in a separate folder. Just so I have my little itunes folder. Want to automate because so many.

So I find my flac folders within my Eminem folder....

```
:~$ find /mnt/music/Eminem -type d -name *FLAC
    /mnt/music/Eminem/2009 Relapse FLAC
    /mnt/music/Eminem/1996 Infinite FLAC
    /mnt/music/Eminem/1999 The Slim Shady LP FLAC
    /mnt/music/Eminem/2000 Marshall Mathers LP FLAC
```

Now instead of going into each folder and converting manually using something like

```
    ffmpeg -i track.flac -acodec alac track.m4a...
```

How do I, within a bash script, take these multiple folders. Create an ALAC copy of the contents in /mnt/music/iTunes using FFMpeg?

New folder will be...

```
/mnt/music/iTunes/Eminem/2009 Relapse ALAC/track.m4a
```

All flac folders have FLAC at the end in the same folder structure.

```
/mnt/music/Artist/Year Album FLAC
```

I understand most of the locating, copying, converting, manually terminal command stuff but when it comes to putting it into a bash script. I don't understand how I take the output of each command and use it for another. The list of folder for example. Don't know how to automate doing all the steps for each.

Kind of long winded but any help will be much appreciated. Even some videos you recommend for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -
cd /mnt/music
for flac in */*FLAC/*.flac; do
  alacdir=iTunes/${flac%FLAC/*}ALAC
  alac=${flac##*/} alac=$alacdir/${alac%.flac}.m4a
  echo mkdir -p "$alacdir" &&
  echo ffmpeg -i "$flac" -acodec alac "$alac"
done
```

Drop `echo`s if you're happy with the output. Leave a comment if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Just realized it does not copy over the album art. Is there something I can add to ensure album art gets copied over?

Comment: @BrettSjoholm I don't know much about ffmpeg, just copied the command from your question